# Connection refused when using load balancing with Traefik 2

Tags: traefik

I have yml configuration file with a router and a service. Every time I get a 404 error. I know the URL works and I can access the server from Traefik server. What am I missing? Also, for some reason the request reroutes to https. Perhaps a conflicting rule?

Also note, Traefik runs in docker, but the connecting server does not. The goal here is to add multiple nodes to the load balancer.

```
http:
  routers:
    demo_1-rtr:
      rule: "Host(`http://demo.lab.local`)"
      service: demo_1
      entryPoints:
        - http
  services:
    demo_1:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://172.16.9.90:16000"
```

Traefik Config:

```
global:
  checkNewVersion: true
  sendAnonymousUsage: true
api:
  insecure: true
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix://var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    directory: /rules
    watch: true
log:
  level: DEBUG
accessLog: {}
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it would be this

`--api.insecure=true` global argument and it should work.

So in your case add the following in traefik.toml

```yaml
[api]
  insecure = true
```

Otherwise I would need more information to debug more.

Comment: That has been set true before I added the load balancer. What do you need to help troubleshoot? I stood up a fresh container with just a single entry point and a single router and service. I still cannot reach the site, the browser states that the connection was refused.

Comment: You can do the following 1) Enable debug level logs in traefik 2) Enable access logs in traefik 3) And you are getting connection refused it maybe that the networks are connected or not as you said one is running on docker and other one is not. So its not able to connect to the process. 4) I need all the config files like Traefik and other services to give more context on what is happening.

Comment: I did come more testing and there are no logs showing when connect with the URL http://demo.lab.local I have no other services running on this instance of Traefik and I have the bare bones Traefik config file, updated above.

Comment: New  development. I saw a post about a similar issue where the browser was interfering with the .local url. I changed the url from demo.lab.local to demo.lab.io and now I am getting a 404 error. If it helps, the server referenced in the LB does have a sec signed SSL cert.